# IBM X3550 M4 no video

Tags: hardware, ibm, imm2

I have an IBM X3550 M4 which does not output any video, not even sure if it POST.

After turning the power on, the IMM fires up and a bit later the server.
After about 20-30 sec the diagnostics error LED is lit and about 3-5 min later the server shuts down. (blinking power led)
I removed all unnecessary components like disks/raid controllers/PCI and swapped CPU, memory, PSU etc. But still no video.

The server has no release hatch for the light diagnostics led panel, so I assume none is present.
No error LED's are lit on the mainboard which would indicate the source of the problem.

I picked up this server at an auction from a company bankruptcy.
Used the server as a lab environment for about 2 months.
Unfortunately, I never took the effort the configure the IMM.
The IMM website is accessible however, I don't have the password and was unable to reset it.
The manual describes you can reset it from the server itself but since it won't boot, I'm stuck.

Anyone an idea what's wrong, a dead motherboard?

Any ideas how to reset the IMM password, is there a jumper workaround?